How to tell if an interaction term should be included based on residual plot?
Applied Linear Regression Models says:

Also, residuals
should be plotted against interaction terms for potential interaction effects not included in
the regression model, such as against $X_1X_2$ , $X_1X_3$ , and $X_2X_3$ , to see whether some or all
of these interaction terms are required in the model.

However I'm not sure what I'm looking for in the plots to determine if a given interaction term should be included. For example, in question 6.10, the plot of $e$ vs $X_1X_2$ looks as follows:

I see two groups (the data includes a binary coded variable $X_3$), but the plot appears similar to $e$ vs $X_1$:

How do I know whether the $X_1X_2$ term is important?

This is an example of an added variable plot: you can find many relevant posts here on CV.  Here's a good answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/414164/919.  Here's another good thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286850.

There are many examples on this site of interaction plots (stored search)
